# Go project with third party packages on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, go

When deploying a Go project to Heroku, installation of the pq package fails. I've posted this in [heroku buildpack github issues](https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go/issues/35#issuecomment-43425915) as well.

Error at deploy time:

```
-----> Running: godep go install -tags heroku ./...
gournay.go:10:3: cannot find package "github.com/lib/pq" in any of:
    /app/tmp/cache/go1.2.1/go/src/pkg/github.com/lib/pq (from $GOROOT)
    /tmp/build_ce268203-801e-4dfc-a56c-d70698d6c5bf/.heroku/g/src/github.com/andyatkinson/gournay/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/lib/pq (from $GOPATH)
    /tmp/build_ce268203-801e-4dfc-a56c-d70698d6c5bf/.heroku/g/src/github.com/lib/pq
godep: go exit status 1
```

`go get` and `go install` run locally as expected. The project is built and running locally. I believe my package structure is correct, and `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` are correct. I am using `godep` which creates the dependencies file below. The source for the pq package appears to be copied into the project, so it seems like it would compile from that source.

```
~/go/src/github.com/andyatkinson/gournay (master) $ cat Godeps/Godeps.json
{
    "ImportPath": "github.com/andyatkinson/gournay",
    "GoVersion": "go1.2.1",
    "Deps": [
        {
            "ImportPath": "github.com/lib/pq",
            "Rev": "c808a1bb644594ca717ac61f71e6b0e454b835e2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something? Anything else I should check? Thanks!

Comment: The buildpack support godep, check the document at https://github.com/tools/godep

Comment: Thanks. I was already using godep. I read through the readme again a few times, tried resetting my godep dependencies, tried a `.godir` file which is not supposed to be necessary, and a few other things, but continued to get the Heroku deploy error.

I tried out [gopack](https://github.com/d2fn/gopack) on the project as a workaround/alternative to godep, and I was able to vendor the dependencies and successfully deploy to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run `godep save` on development?

from godep README:

```
$ godep save
This will save a list of dependencies to the file Godeps/Godeps.json, 
and copy their source code into Godeps/_workspace. Read over its 
contents and make sure it looks reasonable. 
Then commit the file to version control.
```

--- UPDATE ---

I see your repo, and up on heroku http://warm-depths-3154.herokuapp.com/, follow the steps

```
rm -Rf  gopack.config .godir .gopack
godep save
git add --all . // please commit the Godep folder
git commit -m 'using godep, removed gopack'
```

(the commit https://github.com/dukex/gournay/commit/0de2390835357879a34ea452a56eeeb6391e5ba8)

Comment: Yes. After running `godep save`, I ran `cat Godeps/Godeps.json` and pasted the output above. I put the [gournay project](https://github.com/andyatkinson/gournay) on github if you want to try it out with godep.