# Should I commit Godeps/_workspace or is Godeps.json enough?

Tags: git, heroku, go, dependencies

I'm writing a project in Go to be deployed on heroku, managing dependencies with [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep).

When I `godep save`, I get both a `Godeps.json` file listing my dependencies with versions and an `_workspace/` directory with the source for all dependencies copied in.  I'd rather not commit `_workspace`, all that code's already on github elsewhere.  It seems `Godeps.json` has all the information we need to `go get` the version locked dependencies at heroku buildpack time.

[Several](http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358315/407845) recommend committing the full `Godeps/` directory, but others suggest it [might not be necessary](https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/177#issuecomment-37324541).

The godep docs aren't much help:

> This will save a list of dependencies to the file Godeps/Godeps.json, and copy their source code into Godeps/_workspace. Read over its contents and make sure it looks reasonable. Then commit **the file** to version control.

Is Godeps.json **the file**?

Comment: Opened [an issue](https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/131) for documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Official answer:**

From GitHub issue [#131](https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/131#issuecomment-59051250):

> The intended use of `godep` is to vendor dependencies and commit the _workspace directory to version control. See the proposal document by @kr linked in #123 (proposal: http://goo.gl/RpYs8e) As discussed in that proposal, godep used to have a mode (-copy=false) that supported not vendoring the dependencies. My guess is that the ambiguous language in the Readme may be due to that. This mode has been removed as documented in #123.

Here's also `godep` author talking about his project and ideas behind - [Vendoring and Import Path Rewriting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myCHCXFFTPY)

**Personal opinion:**

I don't think there is a right way to do it.

Committing vendor libs does seem awkward, but it has it's advantages:

- You're not relying on external services (GitHub, etc). GitHub has outages, maybe you have some horrible company policy which prevents you from using it, maybe repository disappears or it's history is rewritten, maybe you're behind firewall (staging/build server), etc.
- Each time there are updates to your deps you get a nice diff of what has changed.
  Which helps when updating to newer version, or just keeping track of changes if you screen code that is being used.

At the end it's up to you to weigh the pros and cons. Personally I cringe every time I have to commit vendor code, but in my Go projects I do. At least for now.

Also companies like Google and Facebook mostly keep everything in one repository and that includes vendor code (or so I've heard).

Interesting article on the topic:
 [Go Package Management](http://nathany.com/go-packages/)

Comment: @hurrymap Adding 2 answers isn't really the best practice on SO. So I just swapped around the paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

godep will need the json file in order to read back the dependencies, as shown in [`update.go`](https://github.com/tools/godep/blob/754ee6f4e0e5fc8d0ef2692fb239d15c7a09dd84/update.go#L38-L39).
So that file needs to be versioned.

But then [godep would fill the content of `godep/_workspace`](https://github.com/tools/godep/blob/754ee6f4e0e5fc8d0ef2692fb239d15c7a09dd84/update.go#L72-L75), which means it is a "generated" content: you don't need to version it.

Comment: Sounds right to me, but what do you make of [this branch](https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/compile#L155) in the buildpack?  Looks like it skips `go get`ting dependencies if there's a `Godeps` directory at all...

Comment: @hurrymaplelad it delegates to godep the job to get the dependencies if it detects a `Godeps` folder (which you will have, since you would have versioned `Godeps/Godeps.json`): that sound sensitive. If no `Godeps`, it falls back to direct `go get` calls.

Comment: Right, but `godep go install` won't fetch dependencies, it just compiles and moves binaries.  When I try pushing to heroku without committing _workspace, it complains `cannot find package...`.  I think this is just a limitation of the buildpack.

Answer (score 2):

Just add Godeps.json file to the repo, and _workspace to the .gitignore list :).

While your code should be fully included in your repo, dependencies have to be just referenced somehow (godep.json, package.json, git submodule... you choose), and nothing more than that.
The same tactics apply to npm, bower, apt and all other package managers.

Your repo - your things + references to vendor libs (of course, when it is possible, you cannot reference sourceforge zip file).

As @VonC said, we do not want to version vendor libs.

Comment: This is exactly where my head space is on this. When reviewing PRs I hate looking over Godeps barf. If people need to save the workspace and legitimately vendorize them, I'd rather see that as part of the build and deployment process - not the development process.